# Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic, nVidea Quadro NVS 280 PCi, Eizo S1921 Dual Screen (Twin View) Slow Window Draws

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-9.10, nvidia-quadro

I have been following this Tutorial to get dual monitors working on my box

http://www.dwasifar.com/?p=862&cpage=1#comment-5727

It works! However, when ever I move a window, the redraw of that window takes 3-8 seconds.
Even moving the window takes the same amount of time

Is this being done in software rather than the nVidea hardware? The windows themselves do not respond.

I have seen a few old threads but no relevant fixes - If anyone could suggest a fix I would very much appreciate it.

I have tried:

```
sudo nvidea-xconfig
sudo nvidia-settings
```

Then configure TwinView go to save the config... and the error unable to parse xorg.conf file and the error in the console

```
VALIDATION ERROR: Data incomplete in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf. 
Undefined Device "null" referenced by Screen "Configured Screen Device"

Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 0):

run glxinfo and locate this line

"OpenGL renderer string: "

if it says Mesa then it's software rendering

did you install the proprietary driver for nvidia? if you go System -> Administration -> Hardware Drivers does it list your card in the dialog?

Comment: Yes i did - im using version 173 of the nVidea drivers.
I am having problems writing to the xorg.conf = keeps saying error parsing file... very painful

Comment: Ps the renderer string is Quadro NVS 280 PCI